# Google Architecture Lifecycle Component Not Calling Fragment Lifecycle Events

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components

This is my first attempt at working with the Google Lifecycle Architecture component with Fragments. My app uses MVP with a BaseViewModel for persisting the Presenter across configuration changes.

In my Activities, all Activity lifecycle events are called for the Presenter as expected courtesy of the Lifecycle component; however, none of the Fragment Presenters' lifecycle events are called.

Code Time!

**BaseViewModel.java**

```
public final class BaseViewModel<V extends BaseContract.View, P extends BaseContract.Presenter<V>>
        extends ViewModel {

    private P presenter;

    private static final String TAG = "[" + BaseViewModel.class.getSimpleName() + "] ";

    void setPresenter(P presenter) {
        Log.d(APP_TAG, TAG + "setPresenter presenter: " + presenter);
        if (this.presenter == null) {
            this.presenter = presenter;
        }
    }

    P getPresenter() {
        Log.d(APP_TAG, TAG + "getPresenter presenter: " + presenter);

        return this.presenter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCleared() {
        Log.d(APP_TAG, TAG + "onCleared ");
        super.onCleared();
        presenter.onPresenterDestroy();
        presenter = null;
    }
}
```

**BaseFragment.java**

```
public abstract class BaseFragment<V extends BaseContract.View, R extends BaseContract.Repository, P extends BaseContract.Presenter<V>>
        extends Fragment implements BaseContract.View {

    private final LifecycleRegistry lifecycleRegistry = new LifecycleRegistry(this);
    protected P presenter;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @CallSuper
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        //Initializes the ViewModel
        BaseViewModel<V, P> viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BaseViewModel.class);

        boolean isPresenterCreated = false;

        if (viewModel.getPresenter() == null) {
            viewModel.setPresenter(initPresenter());
            isPresenterCreated = true;
        }

        presenter = viewModel.getPresenter();
        presenter.attachLifecycle(getLifecycle());
        presenter.attachView((V) this);
        presenter.setRepo(initRepository());

        if (isPresenterCreated) {
            presenter.onPresenterCreated();
        } else {
            //Hacky workaround I don't want to use
            presenter.onPresenterRestored();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public LifecycleRegistry getLifecycle() {
        return lifecycleRegistry;
    }

    @CallSuper
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        presenter.detachLifecycle(getLifecycle());
        presenter.detachView();
    }

    protected abstract P initPresenter();
    protected abstract R initRepository();

}
```

**BasePresenter.java**

```
public abstract class BasePresenter<V extends BaseContract.View> implements LifecycleObserver, BaseContract.Presenter<V> {

    private Bundle stateBundle;
    private V view;
    private BaseContract.Repository repo;

    @Override
    final public V getView() {
        return view;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    final public BaseContract.Repository getRepo() {
        return repo;
    }

    @Override
    final public void attachLifecycle(Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        lifecycle.addObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    final public void detachLifecycle(Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        lifecycle.removeObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    final public <R extends BaseContract.Repository> void setRepo(R repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    @Override
    final public void attachView(V view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    final public void detachView() {
        view = null;
    }

    @Override
    final public boolean isViewAttached() {
        return view != null;
    }

    @Override
    final public Bundle getStateBundle() {
        return stateBundle == null
                ? stateBundle = new Bundle()
                : stateBundle;
    }

    @CallSuper
    @Override
    public void onPresenterDestroy() {
        if (stateBundle != null && !stateBundle.isEmpty()) {
            stateBundle.clear();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPresenterCreated() {
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "BasePresenter.OnPresenterCreated");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPresenterRestored() {
        //Hacky
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "BasePresenter.onPresenterRestored");
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(value = Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    void onStart() {
        if (isViewAttached()) {
            onStartWithAttachedView();
        }
    }

    public void onStartWithAttachedView() {

    }
}
```

The Fragment I am testing: 
**GameSituationsFragment.java**

```
public class GameSituationsFragment extends BaseFragment<GameSituationsContract.View,
        GameSituationsContract.Repository, GameSituationsContract.Presenter>
        implements GameSituationsContract.View {
    @BindView(R.id.gs_prev_session_button)
    ImageView prevSessButton;
    @BindView(R.id.gs_next_session_button)
    ImageView nextSessButton;
    @BindView(R.id.gs_selected_session)
    TextView selectedSessionText;

    private static final String TAG = "[" + GameSituationsFragment.class.getSimpleName() + "] ";

    private InteractionListener interactionListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) return;

        if (activity instanceof GameSituationsFragment.InteractionListener) {
            interactionListener = (GameSituationsFragment.InteractionListener) activity;
        } else {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                throw new RuntimeException(activity.toString()
                        + " must implement GameSituationsFragment.InteractionListener");
            } else {
                //Todo what do we want to do?
                Log.e(TAG, activity.toString() + " must implement GameSituationsFragment.InteractionListener");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof GameSituationsFragment.InteractionListener) {
            interactionListener = (GameSituationsFragment.InteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                        + " must implement GameSituationsFragment.InteractionListener");
            } else {
                //Todo what do we want to do?
                Log.e(TAG, context.toString() + " must implement GameSituationsFragment.InteractionListener");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game_situations, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected GameSituationsContract.Presenter initPresenter() {
        return new GameSituationsPresenter();
    }

    @Override
    protected GameSituationsContract.Repository initRepository() {
        return new GameSituationsRepository();
    }

    public interface InteractionListener{
        void onGsNextSessionClicked();
        void onGsPreviousSessionClicked();
    }
}
```

And finally the Fragment's Presenter: 
**GameSituationsPresenter.java**

```
public class GameSituationsPresenter extends BasePresenter<GameSituationsContract.View> implements GameSituationsContract.Presenter{
    GameSituationsRepository repo;

    private Bundle viewStateBundle = getStateBundle();

    private static final String TAG = "[" + GameSituationsPresenter.class.getSimpleName() + "] ";

    @Override
    public void onPresenterCreated(){
        Log.d(APP_TAG, TAG + "onPresenterCreated");
        repo = (GameSituationsRepository) getRepo();
        ...
        initializeViews();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPresenterRestored() {
        //So hacky
        initializeViews();
    }

    //NOT CALLED
    @OnLifecycleEvent(value = Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    protected void onStart(){
        Log.d(APP_TAG, TAG + "onStart");

        if (isViewAttached()) {
        }
    }

    //NOT CALLED
    @OnLifecycleEvent(value = Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    protected void onStop(){
        if (isViewAttached()) {

        }
    }

    //NOT CALLED
    @OnLifecycleEvent(value = Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (isViewAttached()) {
            //Something to do?
        }

        //a little cleanup
        repo = null;
    }

    private void initializeViews(){
        //Do view stuff
    }
}
```

So the question is are fragments able to receive Lifecycle Events or did I miss something in my implementation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you creating your own LifecycleRegistry instead of using the one from the Fragment support package?

Comment: The sample code I followed did this, but your question leads me to believe this may not be the correct course of action. The samples I have seen generally do this, do you have a handy link I can peruse for properly setting up the fragment with the support Lifecycle registry? Also, thanks for the comment, @Chris

Comment: There's a bit of an explanation here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle - TLDR; Fragments and Activities in Support Library 26.1.0 and later already implement the LifecycleOwner interface so you shouldn't need to create your own, if you do then you're responsible for emitting the lifecycle states which I think is one of the issues you're having.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will definitely read through this.